# Argument Error : Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing the following in rails console.

```
> class Hello
>   def method
>     d = Jobs.find_by_sql("select id, count(*) as TOTAL from table group by id having count>100")
>     d.each do |m|
>         puts m.account_id
>       end
>     end
>   end

 => :method 
> Hello.method
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong in this code. How can I solve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your method name "method" is an existing method of the Object class, which is ultimately inherited by all classes in ruby.

You define an **instance method** with this name, which would be fine and would override the inherited instance method if it existed already.  However, when you come to call it, you're calling it as a **class method** (because you're calling it on `Hello`, which is the class), so you're calling the existing "method" method, which is complaining about not getting any parameters.

Change *your* method to be called "foo" and then try to do `Hello.foo`.  You'll get an "undefined method or variable" error because there's no `foo` class method.

Then do

```
hello = Hello.new
hello.foo
```

and it will work.

**EDIT:**

If you want it to actually *be* a class method, then you can do it via either of these ways:

```
class Hello

  def self.method
    d = Jobs.find_by_sql("select id, count(*) as TOTAL from table group by id having count>100")
    d.each do |m|
        puts m.account_id
      end
    end
  end

end
```

or

```
class Hello

  #class methods go in here 
  class << self

    def method
      d = Jobs.find_by_sql("select id, count(*) as TOTAL from table group by id having count>100")
      d.each do |m|
          puts m.account_id
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

As an aside, it's a convention, and generally a good idea, to use **meaningful variable names**.  For example, if you have a variable which is a collection of Job objects, call it "jobs", not "d".  Then anyone reading your code can easily remember what is held in that variable.

Using this principle, i would rewrite your code thus:

```
    def output_job_account_ids
      jobs = Jobs.find_by_sql("select id, count(*) as TOTAL from table group by id having count>100")
      jobs.each do |job|
          puts job.account_id
        end
      end
    end
```

See how it's immediately much more obvious what is happening?  I renamed the method name too: it's generally a good idea to have a method name describe what the method does.